# Redirecting fails in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect

```
public function index()
{
    $this->redirect('/');
}
```

I will just go insane soon... How can it not work? Please help.

**EDIT**: by won't work I mean it gives just blank page.

**EDIT2**: Redirect doesn't work in all controllers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had controller's class like this:

```
<?
class PageController extends AppController
{
```

I had a new line before `<?`, that's why it didn't work. :)

Comment: check model also. white space might be after ?> (closing tag)

Answer (score 0):

If your index() is actually a controller action referring to '/' then you'll have an infinite redirect loop and that could be the cause of your problem.

Please add more context to your question to have a better chance in getting a correct answer.

If you are getting blank pages, could very well be your configuration, try enabling debug by editing the line

`Configure::write('debug', 0)` to `Configure::write('debug', 2)` in your core.php and see what's wrong

Comment: That's not the case. I can change '/' to anything else, still won't work.

Comment: could you add to your question what you mean by "won't work"?

Comment: ok this is getting difficult :(, do you have a live test page I can look at?

Comment: @andres: found my mistake, unbelievable :) will post it in a few secs

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it absolutely

```
$this->redirect('http://www.example.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->redirect(array('url' => '/'));
```

OR

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'examples', 'action' => 'add'));
```